# Does onFailure automatically close the WebSocket connection in OkHttp?

Tags: android, networking, websocket, okhttp

I'm using the OkHttp library for WebSocket connections in Java, and I'm wondering if the onFailure method included in the WebSocketListener class will close the WebSocket connection by default or if I need to manually close the connection myself.

Here's my implementation of the onFailure method:

```java
    public void onFailure(@NonNull WebSocket webSocket, @NonNull Throwable t, @Nullable Response response) {
        super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response);
        if (!webSocket.close(1000, "Connection closed")) {
            webSocket.cancel();
            close();

        }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm manually calling the webSocket.close() method to close the WebSocket connection with a specified status code and reason. I've also included an if statement to check if the WebSocket connection is still open before closing it, and I'm calling the cancel() method to free up any resources held by the WebSocket connection if the close method returns false.

So, my question is: does the onFailure method automatically close the WebSocket connection in OkHttp, or do I need to manually close the connection myself as I've done in my implementation?